# Spring - can't create custom query in CrudRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web-applications

For some reason i get `BeanCreationException` when trying to initialize repository with `findByEmail` method. Don't know what's the cause, field in entity corresponds with arguments in query and packages are scanned in dispatcher servlet.

PersonRepository.java

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import wymysl.model.Person;

@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {

    public List<Person> findByEmail(String Email);

}
```

Person.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Persons")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    protected Integer id_per;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=2, max=30)
    protected String Name;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=2, max=30)
    protected String Surname;

    @NotNull
    @Email
    protected String Email;

    protected String Contact_email;

    protected String Gender;

    protected String City;

    protected String Country;

    protected String Additional;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=6, max=15)
    protected String Password;

    @Transient 
    @NotNull
    @Size(min=6, max=15)
    protected String checkPassword;


    public Person(){

    }

    public Person(String name, String surname, String email, String password) {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Surname = surname;
        this.Email = email;
        this.Password = password;
    }


    public Integer getId_per() {
        return id_per;
    }
    public void setId_per(Integer id_per) {
        this.id_per = id_per;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.Name = name;
    }
    public String getSurname() {
        return Surname;
    }
    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.Surname = surname;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return Email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.Email = email;
    }
    public String getContact_email() {
        return Contact_email;
    }
    public void setContact_email(String contact_email) {
        this.Contact_email = contact_email;
    }
    public String getGender() {
        return Gender;
    }
    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.Gender = gender;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return City;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.City = city;
    }
    public String getCountry() {
        return Country;
    }
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.Country = country;
    }
    public String getAdditional() {
        return Additional;
    }
    public void setAdditional(String additional) {
        this.Additional = additional;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return Password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.Password = password;
    }

    public String getCheckPassword() {
        return checkPassword;
    }

    public void setCheckPassword(String checkPassword) {
        this.checkPassword = checkPassword;
    }

}
```

PersonValidator.java

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

import wymysl.model.Person;
import wymysl.repositories.PersonRepository;

public class PersonValidator implements Validator {

    @Autowired
    PersonRepository repo;

    public boolean supports(Class<?> classz) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Person.class.equals(classz);
    }

    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {

        Person person = (Person) target;

        if(!(person.getPassword().equals(person.getCheckPassword()))){
            errors.rejectValue("Password", "password.nonequal");
        }

        List<Person> emailCheck = repo.findByEmail(person.getEmail());

        if(!emailCheck.isEmpty()) {
            errors.rejectValue("Email", "email.exist");
        }

        repo.save(person);

    }

}
```

Full trace of error :

```
Could not create query metamodel for method public abstract java.util.List wymysl.repositories.PersonRepository.findByEmail(java.lang.String)!
```

Comment: Add the stacktrace please.

Comment: @Jens yeah forgot about it. It's now added

Comment: The list can't have abstract objects the underling framework requires clarification of the list type.

Comment: @Mike that is not the complete stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

I think you left the query annotation off of your repository interface method::

```
@Query
public List<Person> findByEmail(String Email);
```

Comment: I neither see this annotation anywhere in spring-data nor is it mentioned in the docs http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories

Comment: The annotation is definitely there:

Comment: Ah, you're right, there is http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-creating-database-queries-with-the-query-annotation/ - a spring-data-jpa only annotation (which is why I didn't find it, nosql ftw :p) and allows you to specify custom sql queries (which you didn't so maybe adding this would even make it worse?)

Comment: It's strange, that's not even a custom query.  Does the repo work at all, like for saving?  Is everything else set up, like the persistence.xml file?

Comment: The more I think about it (and based on the abstract message in the error), I think your repo is not being processed by spring.

Comment: Every method of an `interface` is implicitly `public abstract` and you would see exactly that method signature via reflection. This happens while spring processes it and tries to auto-create an implementation of the interface. You can find many other cases like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136008/spring-data-jpa-hibernate-propery-prefix but OP has unfortunately not added a proper stacktrace.. Could be because the Person class isn't setup right in this case as well (uppercase field names?)